# How to safely use Baby Bio house plant insecticide spray?

Tags: pesticide, safety, dracaena

I've got a Dracaena plant; that has what appears to be white scale or something like it (see attached photos); I don't know much about plants, I bought this one in Vauxhall Flower market in London a year and a half ago, one month after it started showing these symptoms. I moved home and planned to buy new plants. I don't want the new plants to get infected with the disease, so I got the Baby Bio house plant insecticide spray - but the instructions are not clear about how to use it, and I'm not finding any instructions online, so hopefully I can find help here.
My question is how to safely use Baby Gio house plant insecticide spray? I'm sure this is toxic and should use outdoors, but it's 2C ~ 8C at the time I wrote this post, and surely the plant is going to die if I leave it outside. So, what to do? How long should the plant stay outdoors until the spray effects finish?
Any advice is appreciated! Even if that means throwing the plant away.
Thank you!

- The spray url: http://www.bayergarden.co.uk/Products/b/Baby-Bio-Houseplant-Insecticide

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is white fly.  Instead of spraying I'd use a dip.  NEEM is pretty much similar to your Baby Bio?  Use a paper plate slit once from edge to center, place on the top of this pot.  Mix NEEM as labeled into a 3 gallon container, turn the plant upside down and swish in the solution.  Splash a little on the top of the soil.  Do your have other houseplants?  Check them out as well.  These guys won't hurt your plant too quickly but they need to be controlled.  This dip style is far better than spraying.  Just be vigilant and when you see this again, if you see this again, do the dip.  I also water my indoor plants once every 3 months or so in the shower.  Allow them to drip dry and replace (don't do this right after a dip).

Just noticed the part that this guy is out of doors.  Start acclimating him right now if you want him in doors.  Takes a few weeks ideally.  Still, go ahead and do the dip.  White fly is less of a problem than a plant moved indoors from outdoors too soon.  Again, do you have other indoor plants.  It would be best to do the dip BEFORE starting the acclimation process so less chance of bringing these guys in to bother you and your other plants.